# Javascript not loading on Website but on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html

Please have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/WktTV/2/

I copy and pasted it onto this site: http://investmoney.me/

but it does not load and it is also displaying `â€‹`.

Please help; I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: please have a look at http://investmoney.me/ I added jquery but the problem is still there (the code is clean I checked sereral times)

Answer (score 3):

Look in the error console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Your website is missing jQuery.

Comment: please have a look at http://investmoney.me/ I added jquery but the problem is still there (the code is clean I checked sereral times)

Comment: There are more errors in the console. The code is _not_ "clean." `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Answer (score 2):

You're using jQuery on your page, without loading it previously. Add the following to your page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The `â€‹` also is encoded in your page. Simply delete it.

Comment: please have a look at http://investmoney.me/ I added jquery but the problem is still there (the code is clean I checked sereral times)

Comment: @user1520883 The code is not cleaned up. There is still a `â€‹` in your code right after the last closing `});`. Maybe you should switch your IDE, if it persists on adding such characters.

Comment: my post original source file - your post output source code = to my problem

Comment: @user1520883 As Matt, e.g., sees the same problem, I think this is a problem on your side.

Comment: but as far as I see it I am not doing any thing wrong: plain old source code editing which somewho displayes somthing different - I give up !!!

Comment: @user1520883 Maybe try another editor, something like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined a `$` function.

The jsfiddle version loads one from jQuery 1.7.2.

Comment: please have a look at http://investmoney.me/ I added jquery but the problem is still there (the code is clean I checked sereral times)

Answer (score 1):

If you open your console, you will see the following error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

You're not loading the jQuery library.

Comment: please have a look at http://investmoney.me/ I added jquery but the problem is still there (the code is clean I checked sereral times)

Comment: @user1520883: Check the error console - you're still getting an error.